# How to pass data from one action to another action in the same controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to pass data from one action to another action in the same controller.
I tried using _forward() but that affects the grid. Any other techniques??

I tried using $this->_forward('fullscreen');

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180839/is-it-possible-to-forward-data-to-another-controller-action-in-zend-2

Comment: tried that... shows this error::

 Method "forward" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()